# Add terms to nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a nested list of the following:

```
list={{1,2},{5,8},{4,1}...}
```

I would like to add a number to each first term of the list. The output would be like the following:

> {{1+x,2},{5+x,8},{4+x},1}...}

Comment: {x, 0}+#&/@list

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 8}, {4, 1}};
```

[`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html):

```
{#1 + x, #2} & @@@ list
(* {{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}} *)
```

[`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html):

```
# + {x, 0} & /@ list    
(* {{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}} *)
```

[`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html):

```
Transpose[{list[[All, 1]] + x, list[[All, 2]]}]    
(* {{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}} *)
```

[`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[x + # &, list, {All, 1}]
(* {{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}} *)
```

[`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) only:

```
Transpose[Transpose@list + {x, 0}]
(* {{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}} *)
```

[`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html):

```
Replace[list, {a_, b_} :> {a + x, b}, {1}]
(* {{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}} *)
```

[`Inner`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html):

```
Inner[Plus, list, {x, 0}, List]
(* {{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Don't forget `MapAt[x + # &, list, {All, 1}]`

Comment: I like this format really much

Comment: @JasonB Great, made it community wiki feel free to edit!

Comment: @march The problem with ReplaceAll is: what if `Length[list] == 2`?

Comment: @Szabolcs. Oh. Agreed. I like the `Replace` version better, since fixing the `ReplaceAll` version by doing, for instance, `a_Symbol` won't be general enough.Those not-so-corner cases kill me sometimes.

Comment: `ReplacePart[#, {i_} -> {x, 0}] + # &@list`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 8}, {4, 1}};
```

Using `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
list + Threaded[{x, 0}]
```

{{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}}

Answer (score 3):

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 8}, {4, 1}};

SubsetMap[# + x &, list, {All, 1}]
```

> {{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {5, 8}, {4, 1}};
```

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[list, {a_, b_} :> {a + x, b}]

(*{{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, I have to say that the solution using `Threaded` looks like the nicest one to me. Kudos to @eldo.

I want to demonstrate the use of [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) that was developed by @Sjoerd Smit. To the extend of my knowledge it was first suggested in [**`this answer`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157305/function-addition-declaring-function-as-the-total-of-a-list-of-functions/277661#277661).

In this example we do

```
ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{#1 + x &, #2 &}] @@@ list
```

> `{{1 + x, 2}, {5 + x, 8}, {4 + x, 1}}`

A not so normal way of doing it is to use [**`Outer`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)

```
Transpose[{First /@ Join @@@ Outer[Plus, list, {x, 0}], 
  Last /@ Join @@@ Outer[Plus, list, {x, 0}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list + ConstantArray[{x,0},Length@list]


(* {{1+x,2},{5+x,8},{4+x,1}} *)
```